# CharSequence in Toast animation not appearing? Android

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android  development so here is my problem.
I have an array of buttons which I would like to display a `Toast` saying "This button will launch" + *the button's getText value*  when pressed.

**EDIT**

The declaration and initialization code of the buttons array.

```
 final Button buttons[] = new Button[6];
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
```

So,

```
    for(i = 0; i< buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.d("test","Why is this not appearing in logcat");
                CharSequence buttonvalue = buttons[i].getText();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                System.out.println(buttonvalue);
                CharSequence text = "This button will launch" + buttonvalue + " App!!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

The app compiles fine but crashes as soon as I pressed the buttons.And I can't seem to debug it cause both `System.out.println()` and Logcat is not appearing at all or I am just looking at the wrong place. Where should I find these messages then?

Component Tree:
[image]
Here is a screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Is your buttons[i] is well initialized?

Comment: Show the full code please.

Comment: try this `buttons[i].getText().toString;`

Comment: @ShaishavJogani why would that help? `getText()` returns a `CharSequence`.

Comment: @user13 It return `Editable` which implements `CharSequence` Take a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html

Comment: @ShaishavJogani As i said, `getText()` returns a `CharSeqence`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText() You're basically saying that initializing a `CharSequence` with one of its subclasses should solve this problem. Why would you think that? You're still passing a `CharSequence` to the other methods that way.

Comment: My bad. I though `Button` extends `EditText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to follow my example it's more simple to implement while you dont have a LogCat:

```
 private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5};

private Button[] bt = new Button[idArray.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    for (int i=0; i<idArray.length; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        bt [b] = (Button)findViewById(idArray[b]); // Fetch the view id from array
        bt [b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This button will launch" + bt[b].getText().toString() + " App!!";,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Still crashes when I pressed the buttons.Why must it be a String? also edited my question with more code .

Comment: it's really important to share your Log ! to know the problem

Comment: My log is empty when it crashed.I already shared the screenshot.I found out that the error occurs at the declaration of buttonvalue line cause if i removed it then the app works.

Comment: I've updated my answer try to follow my example it's more sample ! Sorry I can't help you enough  if you dont share you LogCat

Comment: Glad I could help :D